# don't close taskeng on error

Tags: php, windows, scheduled-tasks

I am running php.exe with windows task scheduler. 
The thing is I don't want it(the windows taskeng.exe) to close on error .

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Php\php.exe -f C:\filename.php
```

I have looked for it here
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

but no luck..

Comment: What do you mean by "close on error"? What closes? On what error?

Comment: the windows taskeng.exe . on php error.

Comment: I still don't understand. The script will exit upon an error, there's nothing you can do about that. Do you mean your script runs in a loop and you don't want it to exit upon an error but instead run forever? Then catch the errors before they occur. Please, explain your problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is that a PHP error isn't a problem for windows scheduler.

What you want to do is to write some logging into your script so that if there is an error, it appends to a log/error file.

If you have an error in your script, PHP sees it as an error, but windows scheduler just happily carries on until the end of the output from the script.

You *cannot* get windows scheduler to *stop* as such on a PHP error. Windows Scheduler just runs the code and outputs the errors into the `cmd` window, which still carries on until the last of the output is received - whether it is error message or not. You will have to catch the PHP errors within your code (and log then into a database or a logfile) as Windows Schdeuler will complete with a success the moment the PHP output stops.